# Church Numerals represented as a List?

Tags: lambda-calculus, church-numerals

Afternoon All,

Perhaps an easy one for many, but am new to Lambda calculus:

Is the below list, Ni, a representation of the Church numerals? I think it is but how do I prove it...if not, what is it...?

The terms Ni and N'i for each natural number i are defined as follows.
(n and c are variables while i stands for a number.)

```
          N'0 = n
          N'i = c i N'i−1 for i > 0
          Ni = λc.λn.N'i for any i
```

any help much appreciated...
Kind Regards